# Is it safe to modify a C array concurrently in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays, concurrency

I am exploring concurrent speedup on iOS and just getting started with Objective-C concurrent programming. I am starting with a simple example of grayscaling an image (I know I can more efficiently do this with OpenGL but I think it is a good enough large data-set example to play with).

Basically I am going to split up the image into different quadrants and queue up a set of blocks each with their own quadrant to compute. I am storing the data in a simple `UInt8 *imageData;` array and I am wondering if it will be okay with me accessing this array concurrently. If not is there another data structure which will allow me to do this?

Comment: As long as threads are touching different parts of it you should be fine.

Comment: Okay, good to hear. Thanks!

Comment: Reading concurrently from different threads is fine.

Comment: It won't harm the array no matter how many threads read and write it at once.  Of course, if a reading thread "sees" inconsistent data due to another thread writing at the same instant, that may be a problem for the program as a whole, but the array itself won't care.

Comment: As long as the array parts handled by different cores are split along cache line boundaries, things should work fine.